# Difference between adding class attribute inside static function and by assignment outside class

Tags: python

There is code:

```
class A:  
  @staticmethod
  def g():
    A.__z = 4

print(dir(A))
A.g()
print(dir(A)) # A has attribute _A__z
A.__m = 5
print(dir(A)) # A has attribute _A__z and __m
```

Why the name `__m` is not mangled to `_A__m` but `__z` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) puts it:

> This mangling is done without regard to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs within the definition of a class.

Name mangling occurs at compilation time for code that is lexically inside of a `class` statement. It doesn't occur for code outside of `class` statements. It doesn't occur for code in functions that are defined outside a `class` statement and then added to the class object. It doesn't occur for code dynamically executed by a `exec` or `eval` call inside a `class` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly because you declared it outside the class, and name mangling happens inside classes.